# Preferable way of indicating a specific board on a software platform

Tags: text, architecture

Suppose that a software platform has the following architecture:

- **Workspace A**

  - Board 1
  - Board 2
  - Board 3
- **Workspace B**

  - Board 4
  - Board 5
  - Board 6

And each space is custom-named by users like below:

- **Marketing Projects**

  - Communications
  - Outreach
  - Sales
- **Development Projects**

  - Coding
  - Research
  - QA

If notifications are used to inform the user about activities in boards, which of the following is the more user-friendly approach?
(The main difference is which comes first between the larger workspace and the specific board, and **I'd like to get answers in this aspect.**)

**Option 1**:

- *John* created a new post in `Sales` in `Marketing Projects`.
- This post was shared from `Sales` in `Marketing Projects`.

**Option 2**:

- *John* created a new post in `Marketing Projects` → `Sales`.
- This post was shared from `Marketing Projects` → `Sales`.

Comment: Are the board names unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the board names are unique, the order from option 1 one would be optimal. If multiple boards can have the same name, option 2 would be the fastest for all users to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you are proposing two solutions and giving us option to choose, I would choose option 1.
In my opinion, this is how my cognitive effort in understanding worked as soon as I saw it:

Option 1 -
John Created a post in sales section of Marketing Projects category.

Option 2 -
John create a new post in marketing Projects. ""Short circuit"" Now I am not sure if he create a post called sales or he created a post inside sales section.